# simple login page and welcome page (2 html files) with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I hope not getting some minuses due to my question:
I'm a newbie with angularjs and I want to use it to build a prototype of a real web application, it will be just for demo, the first page has a login page where it redirects to a welcome page with the username shown on top (Welcome John!)
All the tutorials I found are based on a 1 page app, anyone can help me where can I find tutorial for this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually most of the Javascript MVC-s main features belong to single page applications, you should look more the features which belongs to component based solutions.

- One of component based framework in JS is Flight by Twitter. http://twitter.github.io/flight/
- JavascriptMVC http://javascriptmvc.com/

Answer (score 0):

Jurka is right with the MVC features and single page application. To accomplish authentication with Angularjs you'll have to learn about the basic concepts first.

I suggest you first work through the tutorial: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial to get an understanding of the basic concepts.

I have bought the Angularjs Book of O'Reilly which covers also authentication. The book is not perfect but fine for beginners to understand some insights.

Basically all you have to do is create a login page and store the username/password inside a cookie once provided to keep the session up. If you want to authenticate against a server you can set the Basic HTTP Authentication headers in the app.js if you use the angularjs-seed-project (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed). This will ensure that the header is parsed to the server with each request.

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('cc', ['cc.filters', 'cc.services', 'userService', 'formFieldService', 'cc.directives'])
// Define routing
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/user', {templateUrl: 'partials/user.html', controller: UserCtrl});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: MyCtrl2});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/user'});
}])

// Set headers
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"]
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic am9obkBqb2huLmNvbTpibGE=';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
}]);
```

I hope this helps.

Kind regards,
Chris